# Pop3 Authentication Using Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, pop3, email-client

i keep getting authentication failed error after i provide proxy information to Pop3Client. Connection is fine but authentication part gives the following error:
[image]

```
  ProxySettings ProxySetting = new ProxySettings
            {
                Name = "asaf",
                Host = "192.168.3.55",
                Port = 808,
                Auth = new Authorization
                {
                    Type = AuthenticationMethodConstants.Ntlm,
                    User = "User-001",
                    Password = "Deneme123"
                }
    
            };
            using (var client = new Pop3Client())
            {
                client.Timeout = 120000;
                if (ProxySetting != null)
                {
                    client.ProxyClient = ProxySetting.CreateHttpProxyClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Current proxy: " + client.ProxyClient.ProxyHost + ":" + client.ProxyClient.ProxyPort);
                }
                
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
               
                client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 995, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

                client.Authenticate("mcs234@lenfs.onmicrosoft.com", "phtfg456!");
```

Interesting thing is that I just tried the same code with ImapClient with port 993 and it worked just fine. It seems problem is only for Pop3 protocol.